# Swift Array Filter Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to filter out arrays in an array condition

```
public struct SalesDO: Entity {
   public var ID: String = UUID().uuidString
   public var isDeleted: Bool = false
   public var salesItems = [SalesItemDO]()
}

public struct SalesItemDO: Entity {
   public var ID: String = UUID().uuidString
   public var isDeleted: Bool = false
   public var modifiers = [SalesItemModifierDO]()
}

public struct SalesItemModifierDO: Entity {
   public var ID: String = UUID().uuidString
   public var isDeleted: Bool = false
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is to filter out those SalesItem which is not deleted, together with the sales item modifiers inside not deleted as well

I try to use the Swift filter array function, but it is compiler error

```
let rawSales = self.service.getSales(object: SalesDO()) as? SalesDO
if var sales = rawSales {
   let filteredSalesItem = sales.salesItems.filter({$0.modifiers.filter({$0.isDeleted == false})})
}.filter({$0.isDeleted == false})
```

I also tried this code

```
// It becomes SalesItemModifierDO array
let filteredsales = sales.salesItems.flatMap({$0.modifiers.filter({$0.wbDeleted == false})}).filter({$0.wbDeleted == false})
```

For example

```
Item A is not deleted
   => Modifier 1
   => Modifier 2
   => Modifier 3 : Deleted
Item B is deleted 
   => Modifier 1
   => Modifier 2
```

I am trying to achieve a function that will only display Item A with only 2 modifiers, because the modifier 3 is already deleted.

Can someone guide on what I am missing? Any help given is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array to remove sale items that are deleted, then map the remaining ones to remove modifiers where the modifier is deleted.

```
let filteredSalesItem = sales.salesItems.filter({ !$0.isDeleted }).map { (item) -> SalesItemDO in
    var newItem = item // Need to make mutable interim item to change modifiers array
    newItem.modifiers = newItem.modifiers.filter({ !$0.isDeleted })
    return newItem
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the reply. The code above is working for filtering sales items, but the item modifier inside the sales item is not being filtered.

Comment: Just checking - you want to filter out any sales item that is itself deleted, or has a true isDeleted modifier?

Comment: Basically I need to check SalesItems those are not deleted. After filtered the SalesItems those are not deleted, check the modifier inside and only display those are not deleted as well.

Comment: I have made a small change - please try it. It should both out at once.

Comment: Sir, i have updated the question for better clarity. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clarifying question. So any sales item that is deleted should be filtered out, but if the item is not deleted, it should only filter out its modifiers that are deleted?

Comment: @Alvin I have edited again. I have not tested it yet but will soon.

Comment: @Alvin I think I've got it this time! Please see updated answer.

Comment: Now it is working fine! thank you so much sir for the help! you are a life saver